# Выполнение ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "dev" ] В Dockerfile вызывает Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/src/app/.next/build-manifest.json'

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nextjs

Я запускаю docker-compose up --build, но он выдает ошибку: EACCES: ошибка отказа в доступе при запуске приложения ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]. Я знаю, что это проблема с разрешением, но, насколько мне известно, разрешение sudo не требуется для выполнения команд в контексте контейнеров.
Я не могу понять, что могло пойти не так, пробовал все возможные идеи с разданием прав на файл, на папку и пользователи USER root и USER node, однако ничего не выходит.
Выполнив комманду ls -la .next

```
Attaching to next-campus
next-app  | total 2548
next-app  | drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 May 29 07:07 .
next-app  | drwxr-xr-x   18 node     node          4096 May 29 09:29 ..
next-app  | -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           937 May 28 20:14 build-manifest.json
next-app  | drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 May 29 07:07 cache
next-app  | -rw-r--r--    1 root     root            20 May 28 09:33 package.json
next-app  | -rw-r--r--    1 root     root             2 May 28 20:14 react-loadable-manifest.json
next-app  | drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 May 29 07:07 server
next-app  | drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 May 29 07:07 static
next-app  | -rw-r--r--    1 root     root       2573532 May 28 20:14 trace
```

Ниже приведено сообщение об ошибке.

```
Attaching to next-app
next-app  |
next-app  | > campus@0.1.0 dev
next-app  | > next dev
next-app  |
next-app  | ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
next-app  | info  - Loaded env from /usr/src/app/.env
next-app  | [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/src/app/.next/build-manifest.json'] {
next-app  |   errno: -13,
next-app  |   code: 'EACCES',
next-app  |   syscall: 'unlink',
next-app  |   path: '/usr/src/app/.next/build-manifest.json'
next-app  | }
next-app exited with code 1
```

Мои настройки Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.8.0-alpine

ENV PORT 3000

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

#install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install

RUN chmod -R 777 /usr/src/app/.next/build-manifest.json
RUN chown -R root:root /usr/src/*
RUN chmod a+w /usr/src/app -R

# Running the app
ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  next:
    container_name: next-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/dev/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      - /usr/src/app/.next
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Любые возмоные идеи для решения данной проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Комментарии по тексту:

```
FROM node:16.8.0-alpine    
ENV PORT 3000

# Инструкция WORKDIR создает папку, если ее не существует,
# поэтому создавать папку вручную необязательно.
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Так как мы уже находимся в папке /usr/src/app в промежуточном 
# контейнере, то указывать абсолютный путь не нужно.
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app

# Копируется все содержимое текущей папки на хосте в папку /usr/src/app,
# поэтому копировать отдельно два предыдущих файла не нужно.
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install

# У инструкции COPY есть аргумент --chown при работе в Linux контейнерах.
# Лучше использовать его, чтобы не множить слои.
# Если заглянуть в исходники Dockerfile,
# то там создается пользователь node и группа node.
# Попробуйте использовать его вместо root.
RUN chmod -R 777 /usr/src/app/.next/build-manifest.json
RUN chown -R root:root /usr/src/*
RUN chmod a+w /usr/src/app -R

# Running the app
ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

Итоговый Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.8.0-alpine

ENV PORT 3000
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=1000:1000 . .
RUN npm install

ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

Также в docker-compose не нужно прокидывать volume для папок, которые уже скопированы в образ. Если требуется обмен файлами с хостом, то лучше выделить отдельную папку, например, для логов.

Comment: Действительно помогло, спасибо большое